# AWS-SDK for Node.js. How to download a file (image) by providing a URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using an API called Icecat. They are essentially a product catalogue. One of the features they provide is images of their products. To ensure fast delivery and consistent uptime I want to use S3.

Below you can see my method for uploading the files. All i really want to do is get the image from Icecat onto my S3 bucket. So far I have not found an easy way to get a file from a public URL onto your s3 bucket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const testfile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + 'favicon.png'))

const BUCKET_NAME = 'mywishes'
const IAM_USER_KEY = 'xxxx'
const IAM_USER_SECRET = 'yyyy'

export function uploadToS3 (file) { 
    let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
    })

    s3bucket.createBucket(function () {
        const params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: file.key,
            Body: file.body,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentType: file.mime || 'image/jpg'
        }
        s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error in callback')
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('success')
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: If those are real AWS credentials then please create a new set of credentials and immediately deactivate (and ultimately delete) the ones shown.

Comment: Your code has a few problems with it. Please review the two examples for a) creating a bucket and b) uploading to a bucket at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html.